# Is there any way to record a video or take a screenshot when I am in GRUB on a real (non VM) computer?

Tags: grub2, screenshot, desktop-recording

Is it possible to screenshot or record (like OBS) the screen when I am in GRUB on a non Virtual Machine PC with software (without a camera or a phone)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You need an application to run on the system before you can do that, but before you can have apps running, you need to boot the OS. Being at the grub/boot-loader means you haven't booted an OS yet, so you can't run any applications, and so on.

You'll need to get your cell phone camera out.